# how to reflect changes in the document structure within an existing database?

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a question regarding RavenDb:

Let's say I already store a collection of objects of type `Foo` and now make a change to the class `Foo`, let's say, remove a property. How can this change be reflected in the existing database? Or do I need to read all stored instances of old `Foos`, map them manually to the new `Foo` and then upload to the database again?

Any advice how to best handle this type of scenario? I am interested in RavenDB but am mainly concerned about difficulties in wanting to extend a specific class and then wanting to have this change reflected in the document in the db.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For most changes, you don't need to do anything, you can just let RavenDB fix things for you when it next load the object.
For example, when you add a new property, or remove a property.
For more complex stuff, you can run a script (http://ayende.com/blog/157185/awesome-ravendb-feature-of-the-day-evil-patching) that would convert the existing docs from one version to the other).